# solr import files from multiple dataSource entity

Tags: solr, data-import

I am trying to import files from multiple folders.

My `solrconfig.xml` invokes the following file to use it with `org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler`.

```
<dataConfig>  
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
        <document>
            <entity name="files1"
                    dataSource="null"
                    rootEntity="false"
                    processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
                    baseDir="/w/PDF/"
                    fileName=".*\.(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)|(pptx)|(xls)|(xlsx)|(odf)|(txt)|(rtf)|(html)|(htm)|(jpg)"
                    onError="skip"
                    recursive="true">

                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />
                <field column="file" name="fileName"/>

                <entity
                    name="documentImport1"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text">
                    <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
                    <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="text" name="text"/>
                    <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>

                </entity>
            </entity>

            <entity name="files2"
                    dataSource="null"
                    rootEntity="false"
                    processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
                    baseDir="/w/KNOW-HOW/"
                    fileName=".*\.(pdf)|(doc)|(docx)|(ppt)|(pptx)|(xls)|(xlsx)|(odf)|(txt)|(rtf)|(html)|(htm)|(jpg)"
                    onError="skip"
                    recursive="true">

                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />
                <field column="file" name="fileName"/>

                <entity
                    name="documentImport2"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text">
                    <field column="file" name="fileName"/>
                    <field column="Author" name="author" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="title" name="title" meta="true"/>
                    <field column="text" name="text"/>
                    <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>

                </entity>
            </entity>
        </document> 
</dataConfig>
```

During import I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code into this in the second entity: `${files.fileAbsolutePath}` to `${files2.fileAbsolutePath}` .